# Cron based jobs, which are in Database

Tags: java, scala, cron, akka

I am trying to write a process, which reads the cron expression from a set of records stored in database and runs a job (execute a program if that expression triggers in the next one hour). The records with cron expression in the database can have different triggering times (like Friday or hourly etc).

Example of the table with cron expressions.

```
----------

0 0 12 * * ?   , 12Noon, AJOB
----------

0 11 11 11 11 ?  , Nov 11, BJOB
----------

0 15 10 * * ? , EveryDay 10: 15, XJOB
----------
```

Users can update this crons in the table.

What's the best way to design this kind of application?

The major problem I see here is the following: let's say I ran my job every 1 hour and take the records which are scheduled in the next one hour and run my job, This looks all good when the application is up. If the application is down for 2 hours we might miss some jobs which need to triggered at that time.

How to write this kind of application keeping in mind that the application can fail, but we should not miss any crons during the downtime?

The cron API also has `nextTriggerTime`, but much less support on previous trigger time.

Answer (score 2):

Since Akka is one of the question tags, I assume you're looking for some Akka based solution.

For cron-like job scheduler in JVM, maybe go straight with Quartz (as suggested by Ashiq), it is Java and should be straightforward to integrate into a Scala+Akka project. Also, take a look at [akka-quartz-scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler). It integrates with Akka well and it provides the cron utils.

In terms of the application:

1. Maintain a checkpoint table in DB or disk, whichever fits better, to indicate "if cron job ID=X has been run"
2. Your app loads all cron expressions into memory on startup, trigger quartz scheduler on all of them. If the app doesn't crash, it'll keep running.
3. Every time your app runs a cron job successfully, update the checkpoint table.
4. If your app crashes and restarts, lookup the checkpoint table first to understand where it has been, and scheduler the yet-to-finished jobs.

Comment: It depends on how the user gonna updates the cron expressions. If there is a rule "don't update cron expression if it is supposed to start in a hour", then in step 2, only loads cron expressions starting in an hour. You can do it by scheduling a timer task that runs hourly to pull cron expressions from your DB. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Akka Persistence seems like a really good fit around checkpointing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quartz which is a job scheduling library that can be integrated to Java. It can store and trigger cron jobs and simple jobs. It also has misfire policies which you can utilise in case any of the triggers are missed.